# Target child pages with regex

Tags: regex

I need an regex which target all child pages of a certain group of parent pages, but NOT the parent pages them selfes.

To be more specific, I need an expression which targets:

> /categoryA/XXX
>
> /categoryB/YYY
>
> /categoryC/ZZZ

But I do not want to include

> /categoryA/
>
> /categoryB/
>
> /categoryC/

All help much appreciated!

Gustav

Comment: Which language are you using? Javascript? C#? PHP? ..

Comment: That's it `/category./..*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
\/(\w+)\/([a-zA-Z]+)
```

I am assuming that the strings after the categories use letters only.

Input:

> /categoryA/XXX
>
> /categoryB/YYY
>
> /categoryC/ZZZ
>
> /categoryA/
>
> /categoryB/
>
> /categoryC/

Matches:

> /categoryA/XXX
>
> /categoryB/YYY
>
> /categoryC/ZZZ

Answer (score 0):

This one

```
([^\/]+$)
```

targets everything after the last slash

[image: example on regex101]

You could use this in an `if()` statement to filter out what you need, if I understand the question correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Or this one:

```
\/category[A-Z]\/(.*)
```

**In C#**

```
childpage = Regex.Match(target, "/category[A-Z]/(.*)").Groups[1].Value;
```

**In JavaScript**

```
var myregexp = /\/category[A-Z]\/(.*)/;
var match = myregexp.exec(target);
if (match != null) {
    childpage = match[1];
} else {
    childpage = "";
}
```

**In PHP**

```
if (preg_match('%/category[A-Z]/(.*)%', $target, $groups)) {
    $childpage = $groups[1];
} else {
    $childpage = "";
}
```

**In PowerShell**

```
if ($target -match '/category[A-Z]/(.*)') {
    $childpage = $matches[1]
} else {
    $childpage = ''
}
```

**In Python**

```
match = re.search("/category[A-Z]/(.*)", target)
if match:
    childpage = match.group(1)
else:
    childpage = ""
```